# Query ApexEmailNotification in APEX

Tags: soql, email, queryexception

I am trying to query for ApexEmailNotification in APEX, but am not able to.
I am getting this error message

> System.QueryException: sObject type 'ApexEmailNotification' is not supported.

The use case for this is to catch an exception and email the user(s) specified in the ApexEmailNotification.

How can this be done in APEX?

Comment: I think this would work better if you showed us an example of what you tried to do and failed...

Comment: If that object exists, it certainly is not documented in the SOAP API Developer Guide. Why do you think an object with that name exists? If you provide more context, it will be much easier to determine what object you actually meant.

Comment: @SebastianKessel I have emails and users configured in setup -> Email Administration -> Apex Exception Email. If I run `SELECT Email, UserId FROM ApexEmailNotification` in the Query Editor in the Developer Console, the query would be successful and return the correct rows. The problem is I want to query this in APEX, so I can catch and handle an exception in an APEX class. This is where I run into the error. What I specifically tried was run the query in a `without sharing` apex class.

Comment: @AdrianLarson
 [This](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexemailnotification.htm) is the object in question. 
The document happens to list the Supported SOAP API Calls. `query()` appears on the list, which is why I thought it should be working in APEX.

Comment: Jeremy, show us some code please. If it works in the Dev Console it should work on Apex. Let us see what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ApexEmailNotification is available in API version 35.0. Updating the API version of my APEX class solved the issue.

Turns out my class was using an API version older than 35.0, which explains why everything was working in the developer console, but not in the APEX class.